# mute unmute button in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i need some help with my actionscript 3 project. I have a button with a sound in it. I have some code (see below) that when i press the button it plays the sound and if i press the button again it stops the sound (like a mute/unmute button). The problem is that when i press the button to play the sound for the second time it plays two sounds (the same sound twice) and if i press the button to play the sound more times the same sound plays many times. Can you please help me solve the problem? Thank you.

```
   function setMute1(vol){
       sTransform1.volume = vol; 
       SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform1;
  }

   var sTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
   var Mute1:Boolean = true;
   sound1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn1);

   function toggleMuteBtn1(event:Event) {
    if(Mute1 === false) {
        Mute1 = true;
        setMute1(0);
     } else {
         Mute1 = false;
         setMute1(1);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like your problem is within your play function, can you show us that code aswell?

Comment: Do you want to stop the sound or just mute it? That are 2 different things.

Comment: I have only one button that i CLICK to play, mute and unmute the sound. The sound is in the button (assign to that same button).  You have right putvande. The button should play and stop not mute and unmute the sound. Can you help me with the code for a button that plays the sound if it is clickes once and stops the sound if it is clicked twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand you start the sound by assigning it to the buttons hit frame? You need to have the sound started **by the code** in order to control the sound in good way.

Here is an working example based on your code, that loads an external **mp3** file. The sound is played and stopped via the same button.

```
// load the sound
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("loop.mp3"));
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
// tool you need for manipulating the volume;
var sTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
// The sound starts not muted
var Mute1:Boolean = true;
var vol:Number = 0;

sound1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn1);
// Set the sound volume;
function setMute1(vol)
{
    sTransform1.volume = vol;
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform1;
    // Check if sound is muted
    if (vol<=0)
    {
        Mute1 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Mute1 = false;
    }
}
// Start/stop sound
function startOrStop()
{
    if (Mute1 === false)
    {
        myChannel.stop();
        setMute1(0);
    }
    else
    {
        setMute1(1);
        myChannel = mySound.play();
    }
}
// This happens when you click the buttom
function toggleMuteBtn1(event:Event)
{
    startOrStop()
}
```

In **actionscrip 2** there was a function that would **stop all sounds**, in **actionscript 3** you can't do that anymore, but you can still assign sounds to frames.

Comment: Both you answers were great and they help me a lot. Sorry i am new to site and i did not understand: how i upvote the answer?

Comment: Thank you. You click the gray arrow that points upwards. Seems like you need 15 reputation to be able to upvote. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 1):

This example mutes and unmutes the sound. The sound is't stopped, just muted.
Also here the sound must be assigned **in the code**, and not to the frame.

```
// load the sound
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("loop.mp3"));
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
// tool you need for manipulating the volume;
var sTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
// The sound starts not muted
var Mute1:Boolean = true;
var vol:Number = 0;

sound1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn1);
// Set the sound volume;
function setMute1(vol)
{
    sTransform1.volume = vol;
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform1;
    // Check if sound is muted
    if (vol<=0)
    {
        Mute1 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Mute1 = false;
    }
}
// Toggle mute on/off
function toggleMute()
{
    if (Mute1 === false)
    {
        setMute1(0);
    }
    else
    {
        setMute1(1);
    }
}
// This happens when you click the buttom
function toggleMuteBtn1(event:Event)
{
    // if not playing, the sound
    if (myChannel.position != 0) {
    } else {
        myChannel = mySound.play();
    }

    toggleMute();
}
```